# Insert value from two tables based on the rows source table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert

I have two tables A and B each with 1 column for simplicity sake and they are primary Keys.

A  contains the values `(1,2,3)` B contains `(1,2,3)`

The third table needs to be the insertion of both A and B and has a composite primary key.

```
Table C (id, src)
```

If the id is coming from table A I'd like src to be 'A' and if its coming from B then 'B'.

There can be duplicate ID's between the tables but they are not the same item which is why I need to create a composite key based on which table the row is coming from.
I've tried

```
Insert into C (anID, src)
Select
Case when (A.anID is not null) 
  then A.anID else B.anID end,
case when (A.anID is not null) 
  then 'A' else 'B' end
from 
A,
B
```

But my results always end up as just 3 rows `(1, A) (2,A) (3,A)` When there should be 6 rows (one of each of those with a B)

Comment: There's no way for `select * from A,B` to give any null value for any field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into TableC (id, src) 
select ID, 'A' from tableA 
union 
select ID, 'B' from tableB
```